# Deriving continuity equation of pipe flow from divergence-free velocity field of incompressible fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

Consider an incompressible fluid flowing through a cylindrical pipe (axis pointing at $x$-direction) of varying cross-sectional area $A(x)$.
It is known that for incompressible fluid with constant density, the condition $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}=0$ is satisfied, where $\vec{u}$ is the velocity field of the fluid. Since $\vec{u} = (u_x,0,0)$, $\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}=0$, i.e. $u_x=u_x(y,z,t)$; or if we let the fluid to be inviscous and the wall of the pipe be frictionless, $u_x$ should be independent of all spatial coordinates. But by considering mass conservation, $A(x)u_x(x)$ is constant, meaning that if $A(x)$ is not constant, then $u_x(x)$ is also not a constant. What was wrong above?

Comment: If $A(x)$ is not a constant, then it means $\vec{u}=(u_x, u_y, u_z)$ and $\nabla .\vec{u}=0$  means $\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}=0$.